# How to get Current Row Index by selecting anywhere in gridview withour Select command

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to find a `RowIndex` of the current row by selecting anywhere on the `Gridview`  without `SelectCommand`. Basically i need it because i am creating a method which will return the `Object` depending on the `DataKey` of the `SelectedRow`. And i am calling it everywhere on the `Page` and i do not want to write the same code again an again.

Here is what i have.

## On RowDataBound

```
protected void gvOrders_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      var dataKey = gvOrders.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex];

      if (dataKey == null)
            return;

      int orderId = AlwaysConvert.ToInt(dataKey["OrderId"]);

      Order cncOrder = OrderDataSource.Load(orderId);

       // do some work   

    }
}
```

Now i have a 3 `CheckBox` column in gridview, so whenever i check the `CheckBox` state i am doing the following and load the `Object` again and do some database work.

## On CheckBox Change Event

```
protected void cbIsReceived_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow)((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer);
    var dataKey = gvOrders.DataKeys[row.RowIndex];

    if (dataKey == null)
          return null;

    int orderId = AlwaysConvert.ToInt(dataKey["OrderId"]);
    Order cncOrder = OrderDataSource.Load(orderId);

    // find the controls using the current row index
    CheckBox cbIsReceived = (CheckBox)gvOrders.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("cbIsReceived");
    Label receivedDateText = (Label)gvOrders.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("receivedDateText");

    // do some work
}
```

As you can see in both events most of the code is to find the `current RowIndex` and load the `Object` and then do some database work.

if you notice, in both event the arguments supplied is different i.e **OnRowBound** its (GridViewRowEventArgs e) and **OnCheckBox_CheckedChanged** its (EventArgs e).

So for every `CheckBox` column i have to write the same code again and again.

I would like to create  method where i can pass the `Sender` and get the current `RowIndex`  back. I am not sure how to do that. please help.

Comment: What .NET version # is this?

Comment: @D-Sect he is using `var` so it's .NET 3.5 or higher

Answer (score 0):

You can route the events from all 3 `CheckBoxes` to the same method by either:

1. Just supply `cbIsReceived_CheckedChanged` as the event handler for
   all three checkboxes OR:
2. If you've already generated methods to handle the events for all
   the other `CheckBoxes`, then do this for all the auto-generated methods:

   ```
   cbAnotherCheckBox_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

     // call the first method you've already written:
      cbIsReceived_CheckedChanged(sender, e);
   }
   ```

   *Edit:*
   If there are different operations for each of the `CheckBoxes`, then loop through the rows to get the particular `CheckBox` that was checked and then run the operation that's specific to it.

Comment: i dont think thats the best practice, as i have diff operation running  on every checkbox field.